# I have an object which the player can move with the arrow keys, however, I want the object to not be able to leave a JFrame

Tags: java, object

I want the object to be able to go to the edges, but not outside of the frame.

How do I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Goahead and make it. You got our permission ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing that you need to make a collider mesh and attach it to the object that gets moved around on the screen. In addition, you will need to have colliders on the edges of the screen. This allows collision detection to happen and you can decide what to do when those collisions happen.